# How to control a web browser from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Hi i have a simple webbrowser running in the ui thread and i  have a `webbrowser.Document.GeteEmetbyId.Innertext` 
on another thread running in a while loop, but it gives me a error, so i tried using

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
    webbrowser.Document.GeteEmetbyId.Innertext; 
});
```

,but that gave me an error too, my question is, is there a simple way to control a webbrowser from another thread.

I tried looking for the answer from google, but i couldn't find anything that works for me.

My Current Code:

```
 private void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     th = new Thread(fncTh) { IsBackground = true };
     th.Start();

 }

    void fncTh()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string tehe = wb.Document.GetElementById("txtTehtav").InnerText;
            txtVastus.Text = tehe();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the errors you receive? AFAIK the Invoke way is the correct approach, but your code doesn't seem right. It doesn't do anything with Innertext

Comment: You could do it simply by posting a message back to the UI thread. Then let the UI thread handle the update of the front end itself. You'll need something like a Timer running on the UI thread to check for posted messages from the other thread.